# How to display the date and time of last update of a website published via a gitlab pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to indicate the last date and time of update / publication of my site.
I'm using a gitlab pipeline to publish it and I don't really know where to look to achieve this.
I wonder if I should use a Gitlab variable that I would reuse on the front-end (developed with node.js) (?)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) available within the pipeline that you could use.

`CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP`:  The timestamp of the commit in the ISO 8601 format.
`CI_JOB_STARTED_AT`: The UTC datetime when a job started, in ISO 8601 format.
`CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT`: The UTC datetime when the pipeline was created, in ISO 8601 format.